# redirect /foo.html to /foo but not / to /index in nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx

My files on disk have extensions: `index.html`, `a.html`.  I want a request for `http://example.com/a` to load `/var/www/a.html` and `http://example.com/` to load `/var/www/index.html`.  I want any other url to redirect to a canonical url, so `http://example.com/a.html` should redirect to `http://example.com/a`.

My configuration looks like:

```
rewrite ^(/.+)\.html$ $scheme://$host$1 permanent;
location / {
    root   /var/www;
    try_files $uri.html $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

This does redirect `/a.html` to `/a` and succeed at loading `a.html` from disk:

```
$ curl -D- -s http://www.jefftk.com/food.html | grep ^Location
Location: http://www.jefftk.com/food
$ curl -s http://www.jefftk.com/food | grep ^Location
```

But it sends `/` to `/index`:

```
$ curl -s -D- http://www.jefftk.com/pictures/ | grep ^Location
Location: http://www.jefftk.com/pictures/index
$ curl -s -D- http://www.jefftk.com | grep ^Location
Location: http://www.jefftk.com/index
```

If I remove the rewrite rule it stops redirecting from `/a.html` to `/a` but also stops sending `/` to `/index`:

```
$ curl -D- -s http://www.jefftk.com/food.html | grep ^Location
$ curl -D- -s http://www.jefftk.com/food | grep ^Location
$ curl -D- -s http://www.jefftk.com/ | grep ^Location
$ curl -D- -s http://www.jefftk.com/pictures/ | grep ^Location
```

Why would this happen?  Can I make nginx to both things I want (no `.html` extension, no `index` in url) at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I think your rewrite rule might be backwards. Maybe simply this (no rewrite rule):

```
location / {
    try_files $uri.html $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location = / {
    index index.html;
}
```

EDITED VERSION:

Sorry, I wasn't understanding your description completely. I reread it several times and tested this and it might be closing to what you are looking to do:

```
location = / {
    try_files /index.html =404;
}

location = /index {
    return 301 $scheme://$host;
}

location ~* \.html$ {
    rewrite ^(.+)\.html$ $scheme://$host$1 permanent;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri.html $uri/ @backend;
}

location @backend {
    # rewrite or do whatever is default for your setup
    rewrite ^ /index.html last;
    // or return 404;
}
```

CODE EXAMPLE (REVISION 3):

I'm hoping the third time is a charm. Maybe this will solve your problem?

```
# example.com/index gets redirected to example.com/

location ~* ^(.*)/index$ {
    return 301 $scheme://$host$1/;
}

# example.com/foo/ loads example.com/foo/index.html

location ~* ^(.*)/$ {
    try_files $1/index.html @backend;
}

# example.com/a.html gets redirected to example.com/a

location ~* \.html$ {
    rewrite ^(.+)\.html$ $scheme://$host$1 permanent;
}

# anything else not processed by the above rules:
# * example.com/a will load example.com/a.html
# * or if that fails, example.com/a/index.html

location / {
    try_files $uri.html $uri/index.html @backend;
}

# default handler
# * return error or redirect to base index.html page, etc.

location @backend {
    return 404;
}
```

Comment: That's not going to redirect `http://example.com/file.html` to `http://example.com/file`, though.

Comment: Sorry, I did not completely understanding your question but have reread it over and test some new rules. I've revised the code above to include additional locations.

Comment: This didn't work either: while / doesn't redirect to /index, /foo still redirects to /foo/index

Comment: OK, I've updated the code example and posted the edited revision (#3) above. Would this work?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri.html $uri/index.html =404;
}
```

Basically this will try the `a.html` file first, if that fails it will then try `index.html` and last show a `404`. Also please remember to `restart nginx` after you edit your `vhost` file.