# How to remove and Redirect away from static .html endings on Nginx?

Tags: html, redirect, nginx, varnish

Currently I am using the following config file in an attempt to change all URLs from example.com/page.html to example.com/page.html. Page.html should no longer be accessible for SEO reasons, it should be a pretty simple redirect. After searching, I found the following code:

```
server {

        listen  myip8:8080;
        root /mydir;
        index index.html index.htm;
        server_name example.com;

# example.com/index gets redirected to example.com/

location ~* ^(.*)/index$ {
    return 301 $scheme://$host$1/;
}

# example.com/foo/ loads example.com/foo/index.html

location ~* ^(.*)/$ {
    try_files $1/index.html @backend;
}

# example.com/a.html gets redirected to example.com/a

location ~* \.html$ {
    rewrite ^(.+)\.html$ $scheme://$host$1 permanent;
}

# anything else not processed by the above rules:
# * example.com/a will load example.com/a.html
# * or if that fails, example.com/a/index.html

location / {
    try_files $uri.html $uri/index.html @backend;
}

# default handler
# * return error or redirect to base index.html page, etc.

location @backend {
    return 404;
}
```

However, I am experiencing a problem. All of my static assets cannot be found. CSS, JS, etc just give a 404 error.

What in that code could be causing the 404s?

Also, it's worth noting my server setup. I have two separate VPSs. A varnish and an Nginx. The Varnish server proxies requests to Nginx. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with this.
Finally, the original thread from which I found the code was this one: [redirect /foo.html to /foo but not / to /index in nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961825/redirect-foo-html-to-foo-but-not-to-index-in-nginx)
It appeared to work for OP there but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yea This is very logical, because you're never trying to access `$uri` by it self, so the server tries `example.com/images/image.png.html` for example.

Since you already handled the `html` case above, you should add `$uri` as a first priority.

```
try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/index.html @backend;
```

Comment: That fixed it. I knew it would be something small like that. I really appreciate the help.